# Exporting uneven nested cells from Matlab to excel

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have in Matlab a 1x50 nested cell array where each cell has 3 columns but different number of rows that I need to export to excel.
I already have a loop to obtain the nested cell variable so I am using xlswrite('mydata.xlsx',data,'Sheet1') in the loop.
How can I move 3 columns to the right in every iteration so the data is not overwritten in columns A:C everytime?

I tried looping the range 1:3:length but that just made a mess in the final file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing cells can be quite tricky in Matlab and needs you to play a little with them to get better understanding how you can access different fields. You will also need to get to understand better the difference between bracket `(` and curly bracket `{`because you might easily overlook them in the code.

Now assuming the length of rows in each column triplet is the same, the approach I would take will be to create a new full 'not-nested' cell that I will write to the xls file. The rest of the job is to simply get the indexing right in the for loops. So, I will first find number of columns, then the number of rows in each column triplets. Then create a bigger empty cell, that will be filled with your original 'uneven cell'. Below is a code that might be helpful. *If I am correct, the number of rows in each column triplet has to be same, as otherwise they could not create a triplet then.*

```
% your cell or similar
MyCell1 = {[1,1,1],[2,2,2;3,3,3],[4,4,4;5,5,5;6,6,6]};
%MyCell1 = {['A','A','A'],['B','B','B';'C','C','C'],['D','D','D';'E','E','E';'F','F','F']};

% first find the number of columns
NumOfColum = 0;
for m = 1:1:size(MyCell1,2)
    NumOfColum = NumOfColum+size(MyCell1{m},2);
end

% now find the number of rows for each triplet
RowLength = zeros(1,NumOfColum);
StartIdx = 1;
for m = 1:1:size(MyCell1,2)
    EndIdx = (m-1)*size(MyCell1{m},2)+size(MyCell1{m},2);
    RowLength(StartIdx:EndIdx) = ones(1,size(MyCell1{m},2))*size(MyCell1{m},1);
    StartIdx = StartIdx+size(MyCell1{m},2);
end

% the final size of your Cell2XLS will be 
NumOfRows = max(RowLength);
Cell2XLS = cell(NumOfRows,NumOfColum);

% now copy 'uneven neste cell' to new cell
ColumnIdx = 0;
for m = 1:1:size(MyCell1,2)
    for n = 1:1:size(MyCell1{m},2)
        ColumnIdx = ColumnIdx+1;
        for o = 1:1:RowLength(ColumnIdx)
            Cell2XLS{o,ColumnIdx} = MyCell1{m}(o,n);
        end
    end
end

xlswrite('MyData',Cell2XLS)
```

There might be other options, like formating the `xlRange` argument of `xlswrite` function, however this will be also quite difficult, especially if the length of your cell will be greater than the number of chars in analfabet. Also, calling xlswrite function this many times will make your saving quite slow and I would not recommend it for bigger number of xls file enteries. The more advanced approach would be to establis a COM server connection with your xls file.

Comment: I get an error saying 'the specified data range is invalid or too large. Try using excel A1 notation, for example A1:D4